# Select query to a DB2 table returns an arrow like symbol in java which throws an exception?

Tags: java, db2

I am trying to read a Column named EMP_NAME from a DB2 Table. It works fine for most of the records however it throws an exception for certain records in my catch block.

for example i have included an image of String with a special character in it which i believe is causing the error to happn. I am not sure how can i tackle this on the Java end since resultSet.getString("EMP_NAME"); throws direct error and unable to convert it ? I am okay to convert the arrow into blank but i don't think so it is possible ?

```
while (resultSet.next()) 
        { 
            String NAME = resultSet.getString("EMP_NAME");      
        }
```

One of the resultSet.getString("EMP_NAME"); returns the below string from the DB2 database note there is a symbol like an arrow marked in red i beleive that is causing some record to throw the below exception

[image]

Error Code:

```
from the method getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails()----- com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.63.123] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:663)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:112)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.a(ic.java:2820)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.p(ic.java:521)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.N(ic.java:1558)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.e(vn.java:1147)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.getString(vn.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.getString(vn.java:1698)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails(CreateChart.java:330)
    at CreateChart.iterateDirectReportNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:594)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForDirectReport(CreateChart.java:295)
    at CreateChart.iterateSecondLineManagerNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:562)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForSecondLine(CreateChart.java:251)
    at CreateChart.iterateThirdLineManagerNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:533)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForThirdLine(CreateChart.java:208)
    at CreateChart.iterateDirectorNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:506)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForDirector(CreateChart.java:168)
    at CreateChart.iterateVPNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:472)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForVp(CreateChart.java:126)
    at CreateChart.iterateFuncVPNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:434)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForFuncVp(CreateChart.java:95)
    at CreateChart.main(CreateChart.java:613)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 186
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t.a(t.java:19)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.a(ic.java:2816)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.io.MalformedInputException
    at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t.a(t.java:16)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: ... do you not know for sure?  Try getting _just_ that record.  It looks like the character should be an apostrophe (`'`), contextually (I don't know what's actually encoded).  Are you allowed to fix the database if there's something wrong with the data?

Comment: As the [manual says](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjcsqc.html), "_Call SQLException.getMessage to retrieve specific information about the problem._"